# postgresql: Join n-th row

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table users and a table orders.

The table users has a primary key `user_id` and some other fields. The table orders has a foreign key `user_id`, a name `order_name` and a date `order_date`.

For a legacy export, I need to build a query that returns the data in the form
`user_id | order_name1 | order_name2 | order_name3` where order 1-3 are the three most recent orders of the customers.

My idea is to query on customers and make three joins with select to orders

```
SELECT 
 users.*,
 order1.order_name AS order_name1,
 order2.order_name AS order_name2,
 order3.order_name AS order_name3
 FROM users AS users
JOIN (
 SELECT
  user_id,
  order_name,
  order_date
 FROM orders ORDER BY order_date DESC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1)
AS order1 ON order1.user_id=users.user_id
JOIN (
 SELECT
  user_id,
  order_name,
  order_date
 FROM orders ORDER BY order_date DESC OFFSET 1 LIMIT 1)
AS order2 ON order2.user_id=users.user_id
JOIN (
 SELECT
  user_id,
  order_name,
  order_date
 FROM orders ORDER BY order_date DESC OFFSET 2 LIMIT 1)
AS order3 ON order3.user_id=users.user_id
```

However, this does not work as it only returns one row each from orders, and not specifically for each user.

How to write such a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) to number the rows for each user:

```
SELECT users.*,
       o.order_name,
       o.rn as order_number
FROM users AS users
JOIN ( SELECT user_id,
              order_name,
              order_date, 
              row_number() over (Partition by user_id) order by order_date desc as rn
       FROM orders
) AS o ON o.user_id = users.user_id and o.rn <= 3;
```

However the above will not give you three columns, but three rows for each user. To convert that into columns, you need to apply the poor man's pivot pattern by applying a `group by`:

```
SELECT users.user_id,
       max(case when o.rn = 1 then o.order_name end) as order_name1,
       max(case when o.rn = 2 then o.order_name end) as order_name2,
       max(case when o.rn = 3 then o.order_name end) as order_name3
FROM users AS users
JOIN ( SELECT user_id,
              order_name,
              order_date, 
              row_number() over (Partition by user_id) order by order_date desc as rn
       FROM orders
) AS o ON o.user_id = users.user_id and o.rn <= 3;
GROUP BY users.user_id;
```

If `users.user_id` is the primary key of that table, you can add additional columns from the `users` table without the need to add them to the `group by`.

Since Postgres 9.4, the expression

```
max(case when o.rn = 1 then o.order_name end) as order_name1
```

can also be written as:

```
max(o.order_name) filter (where o.rn = 1) as order_name1
```

Comment: You saved my life! Thanks for pointing out the window function!